# how to start a load based opsworks instance?

Tags: autoscaling, aws-opsworks

I have a stack with a few different layers, one of which is a customer layer. I have setup Load based instances and a load balancer on that layer. This layer has a load balancer as well as auto-healing set to on. How do I start these load based instances up? It looks like just setting up is not enough. What triggers OpwsWorks to start these instances?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you goto "Load Based" tab and turn on scaling configuration and it will present you different scaling options to configure which will actually turn on that instance at specific load. [image]

Comment: thanks! I needed to know how to automate startup of first instance. Turns out there is none and there might not be any in the near future. https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=690900#690900